# Difference between .svm files and .dat files in Dlib

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, object-detection, dlib

I am new to Dlib and was looking through the exams that it comes with, I amd trying to build a car detector using an SVM and was wondering what the difference between a .svm file and a .dat file.

I am asking this because the example projects are all using .dat files for object detection but when training a detector it gets saved as a .svm.

Any information about the differences would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The file extensions are not significant. Nothing in dlib looks at the file extensions.  You can name them anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding:

In dlib `.svm` files are created when we feed train data to `train_simple_object_detector()`. We can use this same `.svm` file to detect the object in the image (in your case, its cars).

Also, `.dat` file is created when you feed train data to `train_shape_predictor()`. We use this to detect and shape in the object.

So we use both the files to detect the object and shape in the image.

Comment: It would be great if you could post links with sources about this.